# How to save zxing barcode scan results to a database?

Tags: android, database, zxing

I'm working on a project that takes student attendance using a camera based barcode scanner. i'm using zxing as a barcode canner. i followed instructions on a web page and created a package and added two files called IntentResult.java and IntentIntegrater.java
these are the files.

intentResult.java

```
package google.zxing.integration.android;
public final class IntentResult {
private final String contents;
private final String formatName;
private final byte[] rawBytes;
private final Integer orientation;
private final String errorCorrectionLevel;
IntentResult() {
    this(null, null, null, null, null);
}
IntentResult(String contents,
             String formatName,
             byte[] rawBytes,
             Integer orientation,
             String errorCorrectionLevel) {
    this.contents = contents;
    this.formatName = formatName;
    this.rawBytes = rawBytes;
    this.orientation = orientation;
    this.errorCorrectionLevel = errorCorrectionLevel;
}
public String getContents() {
    return contents;
}
public String getFormatName() {
    return formatName;
}
public byte[] getRawBytes() {
    return rawBytes;
}
public Integer getOrientation() {
    return orientation;
}
public String getErrorCorrectionLevel() {
    return errorCorrectionLevel;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder dialogText = new StringBuilder(100);
    dialogText.append("Format: ").append(formatName).append('\n');
    dialogText.append("Contents: ").append(contents).append('\n');
    int rawBytesLength = rawBytes == null ? 0 : rawBytes.length;
    dialogText.append("Raw bytes: (").append(rawBytesLength).append(" bytes)\n");
    dialogText.append("Orientation: ").append(orientation).append('\n');
    dialogText.append("EC level: ").append(errorCorrectionLevel).append('\n');
    return dialogText.toString();
}
}
```

and IntentIntegrater.java`

```
package google.zxing.integration.android;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class IntentIntegrator {

public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0x0000c0de; // Only use bottom 16 bits
private static final String TAG = IntentIntegrator.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String DEFAULT_TITLE = "Install Barcode Scanner?";
public static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE =
        "This application requires Barcode Scanner. Would you like to install it?";
public static final String DEFAULT_YES = "Yes";
public static final String DEFAULT_NO = "No";
private static final String BS_PACKAGE = "com.google.zxing.client.android";
private static final String BSPLUS_PACKAGE = "com.srowen.bs.android";
// supported barcode formats
public static final Collection<String> PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES = list("UPC_A", "UPC_E", "EAN_8", "EAN_13", "RSS_14");
public static final Collection<String> ONE_D_CODE_TYPES =
        list("UPC_A", "UPC_E", "EAN_8", "EAN_13", "CODE_39", "CODE_93", "CODE_128",
                "ITF", "RSS_14", "RSS_EXPANDED");
public static final Collection<String> QR_CODE_TYPES = Collections.singleton("QR_CODE");
public static final Collection<String> DATA_MATRIX_TYPES = Collections.singleton("DATA_MATRIX");
public static final Collection<String> ALL_CODE_TYPES = null;
public static final List<String> TARGET_BARCODE_SCANNER_ONLY = Collections.singletonList(BS_PACKAGE);
public static final List<String> TARGET_ALL_KNOWN = list(
        BS_PACKAGE, // Barcode Scanner
        BSPLUS_PACKAGE, // Barcode Scanner+
        BSPLUS_PACKAGE + ".simple" // Barcode Scanner+ Simple
// What else supports this intent?
);
private final Activity activity;
private String title;
private String message;
private String buttonYes;
private String buttonNo;
private List<String> targetApplications;
private final Map<String,Object> moreExtras;
public IntentIntegrator(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    title = DEFAULT_TITLE;
    message = DEFAULT_MESSAGE;
    buttonYes = DEFAULT_YES;
    buttonNo = DEFAULT_NO;
    targetApplications = TARGET_ALL_KNOWN;
    moreExtras = new HashMap<String,Object>(3);
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public void setTitleByID(int titleID) {
    title = activity.getString(titleID);
}
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
public void setMessageByID(int messageID) {
    message = activity.getString(messageID);
}
public String getButtonYes() {
    return buttonYes;
}
public void setButtonYes(String buttonYes) {
    this.buttonYes = buttonYes;
}
public void setButtonYesByID(int buttonYesID) {
    buttonYes = activity.getString(buttonYesID);
}
public String getButtonNo() {
    return buttonNo;
}
public void setButtonNo(String buttonNo) {
    this.buttonNo = buttonNo;
}
public void setButtonNoByID(int buttonNoID) {
    buttonNo = activity.getString(buttonNoID);
}
public Collection<String> getTargetApplications() {
    return targetApplications;
}
public final void setTargetApplications(List<String> targetApplications) {
    if (targetApplications.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No target applications");
    }
    this.targetApplications = targetApplications;
}
public void setSingleTargetApplication(String targetApplication) {
    this.targetApplications = Collections.singletonList(targetApplication);
}
public Map<String,?> getMoreExtras() {
    return moreExtras;
}
public final void addExtra(String key, Object value) {
    moreExtras.put(key, value);
}
public final AlertDialog initiateScan() {
    return initiateScan(ALL_CODE_TYPES);
}
public final AlertDialog initiateScan(Collection<String> desiredBarcodeFormats) {
    Intent intentScan = new Intent(BS_PACKAGE + ".SCAN");
    intentScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
// check which types of codes to scan for
    if (desiredBarcodeFormats != null) {
// set the desired barcode types
        StringBuilder joinedByComma = new StringBuilder();
        for (String format : desiredBarcodeFormats) {
            if (joinedByComma.length() > 0) {
                joinedByComma.append(',');
            }
            joinedByComma.append(format);
        }
        intentScan.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", joinedByComma.toString());
    }
    String targetAppPackage = findTargetAppPackage(intentScan);
    if (targetAppPackage == null) {
        return showDownloadDialog();
    }
    intentScan.setPackage(targetAppPackage);
    intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    attachMoreExtras(intentScan);
    startActivityForResult(intentScan, REQUEST_CODE);
    return null;
}
protected void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int code) {
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, code);
}
private String findTargetAppPackage(Intent intent) {
    PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> availableApps = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if (availableApps != null) {
        for (ResolveInfo availableApp : availableApps) {
            String packageName = availableApp.activityInfo.packageName;
            if (targetApplications.contains(packageName)) {
                return packageName;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
private AlertDialog showDownloadDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
    downloadDialog.setMessage(message);
    downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(buttonYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            String packageName = targetApplications.get(0);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            try {
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
// Hmm, market is not installed
                Log.w(TAG, "Google Play is not installed; cannot install " + packageName);
            }
        }
    });
    downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(buttonNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {}
    });
    return downloadDialog.show();
}
public static IntentResult parseActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String formatName = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            byte[] rawBytes = intent.getByteArrayExtra("SCAN_RESULT_BYTES");
            int intentOrientation = intent.getIntExtra("SCAN_RESULT_ORIENTATION", Integer.MIN_VALUE);
            Integer orientation = intentOrientation == Integer.MIN_VALUE ? null : intentOrientation;
            String errorCorrectionLevel = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL");
            return new IntentResult(contents,
                    formatName,
                    rawBytes,
                    orientation,
                    errorCorrectionLevel);
        }
        return new IntentResult();
    }
    return null;
}
public final AlertDialog shareText(CharSequence text, CharSequence type) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.setAction(BS_PACKAGE + ".ENCODE");
    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", type);
    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", text);
    String targetAppPackage = findTargetAppPackage(intent);
    if (targetAppPackage == null) {
        return showDownloadDialog();
    }
    intent.setPackage(targetAppPackage);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    attachMoreExtras(intent);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
    return null;
}
private static List<String> list(String... values) {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(values));
}
private void attachMoreExtras(Intent intent) {
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : moreExtras.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
// Kind of hacky
        if (value instanceof Integer) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Integer) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Long) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Long) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Boolean) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Double) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Double) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Float) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Float) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Bundle) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Bundle) value);
        } else {
            intent.putExtra(key, value.toString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

And Barcodereader.java page where i call the two classes

```
package com.example.marys.barcodereader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BarReader extends AppCompatActivity {

static final String ACTION_SCAN = "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //set the main content layout of the Activity
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bar_reader);
}

//product barcode mode
public void scanBar(View v) {
    try {
        //start the scanning activity from the com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        //on catch, show the download dialog
        showDialog(BarReader.this, "No Scanner Found", "Download a scanner code activity?", "Yes", "No").show();
    }
}

//product qr code mode
public void scanQR(View v) {
    try {
        //start the scanning activity from the com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        //on catch, show the download dialog
        showDialog(BarReader.this, "No Scanner Found", "Download a scanner code activity?", "Yes", "No").show();
    }
}

//alert dialog for downloadDialog
private static AlertDialog showDialog(final Activity act, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, CharSequence buttonYes, CharSequence buttonNo) {
    AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
    downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
    downloadDialog.setMessage(message);
    downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(buttonYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:" + "com.google.zxing.client.android");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            try {
                act.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

            }
        }
    });
    downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(buttonNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        }
    });
    return downloadDialog.show();
}

//on ActivityResult method
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //get the extras that are returned from the intent
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Content:" + contents + " Format:" + format, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}

}
```

I didn't make the zxing as a library. If i should tell me. At the moment when you first run the app it make you download a barcode scanner from google store.
I hope this is enough. If you need any more information let me know. Thanks in advance
`

Comment: There is nothing unique to barcode results with respect to Android databases. You would write the URL, address, or whatever you decode from the barcode to a SQLite table of your own design, using `SQLiteOpenHelper` (or wrappers around that, like Room or third-party ORMs). There is quite a bit written up already about how to work with SQLite on Android.

Comment: use blob datatype and store

Comment: I need alittle more than what you guys are giving me. 'm new to android studio

Comment: Like how do i get whatever zxing has scanned into a database